# Why does "it" have a dehumanizing connotation?

Tags: pronouns, gender-neutral

There are a number of questions here on gender neutral pronouns, and one of the things that always comes up is that "it" should never be used to refer to a person (usually an adult). The general reasoning for this rule is that "it" is used to refer to animals (in some cases), and inanimate objects. Basically, it's considered dehumanizing.

What I haven't seen, though, is an explanation for **why** it's considered dehumanizing (other than the circular logic that it's only used for non-human subjects).

Comment: Hi! It is me. I'm a human being. Or am I?

Comment: Oh, right! It's you, @coleopterist! Do you feel "dehumanised"?

Comment: @coleopterist but that's the dummy *it*.

Comment: @cornbreadninja Who are you calling a dummy?

Comment: @Zairja it, of course.

Comment: "It puts the lotion on its skin."

Comment: Babies are often referred to as 'it'.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas - I thought about mentioning that, since it seems to be dehumanizing only when referring to adults, but felt it would take away from the question, by distracting people over the meaning of "it" in the context of referring to infants.

Comment: "It is me" is like "It is raining". It only fulfills the grammatical need for a subject, since in English we cannot elide subjects from sentences. (Not without eliding the predicats too.).  Valid answers to "Who is it?" are "It is me" or just "me". But not "is me".

Comment: @kaz Or to us purists, "It is I." But that's another subject.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Old English was highly inflected and the third person singular personal pronoun had masculine, feminine and neuter forms. The neuter form was, in the nominative, *hit*, which became modern English *it*.  English grammatical gender has disappeared, but we retain *he* and *she* to refer to nouns which clearly describe male and female entities, mostly people. The neuter *it* refers to everything else.

Answer (score 22):

The fact that *it* is not used for humans is why its use on humans is dehumanizing. We don't refer to those odd-shaped things at the ends of your arms as "paws"; if I call them "paws" I am connoting "animal" instead of "human". The long history of *it* reinforces it. Also, we have pronouns for humans. So using a non-human pronoun for a human must imply *something*, right? Otherwise, why not just use the human pronoun?

The original choice of words may be arbitrary. The fact that the original speakers distinguished between humans and non-humans may be a relic of culture or random chance. But the centuries of usage reinforce the meanings. It is a feedback-loop. Children learn not to use the language a certain (arbitrary) way and that learning becomes entrenched. The connotations become a feature of the language because of continuous reinforcement. Then, when someone violates the convention, it draws attention to itself.

Comment: Circular logic is circular!

Comment: @Shauna: exactly. For many seemingly arbitrary alternatives in language, the reason, the answer to why, can only be 'because that's the way it is'. One can always ask how it got that way, or what is the phenomenon exactly, but the why question almost always presupposes some sentient designer of the process, when there hardly ever is.

Comment: @Mitch - Since when does asking why presuppose a sentient designer? If someone asked you "why is the sky blue?", what would you answer? According to your comment, it would presuppose that "because $deity made it that way" would be *the* answer (sentient designer), instead of something along the lines of "because the sun's rays are refracted by the earth's atmosphere" (non-designed phenomenon).

Comment: @Shauna: It isn't circular logic. It's a feedback loop. At one point, people just grunted and waved their arms. Eventually they formed words and started using some words to mean some things, other words to mean other things. As this usage becomes entrenched, the connotations develop. As the connotations develop, they reinforce the usage.

Comment: @Shauna That's a fair assessment, but I posit that all "why" questions must ultimately be tautological. For at least two thousand years there has existed the idea of a Chain of Being. At the top is the deity, further down are humans, and below us are the animals. This idea is reflected in language, but, as with any "strange loop", the language reinforces the idea. It's like a positive feedback loop. One may study how language and culture evolve and why some elements are carried on, but how productive or answerable is a question like "Why is the Northern cities vowel shift occurring?"

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 Precisely. I didn't see your comment until mine was posted, but the "feedback loop" is a good analogy.

Comment: Shauna and Mitch - You can think about "Why" a little more deeply than that.  Aristotle distinguished between four types of causes, and when you ask "why" about something you might be asking about any of the four.  Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_causes.

Comment: Well, but surely the English language DOES have a sentient designer, or rather, a long series of sentient designers. English is something invented by human beings: it's not like a grammar book just burst out of a volcano one day. Sure, it's true that it is not a matter of one person sitting down one day and saying, "I think I'll invent a new language! Let's see, what tenses should it have ..." But there were thinking beings behind the entire process.

Comment: @Jay the users of English are sentient, but the language evolves. Words mean what they mean because the speaker and listener agree on what they mean. And the original question was about "dehumanizing", not etymology. So asking the first person who used a different pronoun for an animal than a person "why did you do that?" doesn't necessarily prove anything about why people feel dehumanized today if you call them "it".

Answer (score 3):

At some point people decided that humans should be referred to as "he" and "she" and inanimate objects as "it". I don't know exactly who made that decision and when, or if there is anyone who does. Whether some committee was convened to decide on proper pronoun usage (which I doubt), or whether it shook out over a period of time, is irrelevant. The decision was made. From that point on, referring to another human as "it" implied that you do not consider them a person.

This is not really "circular logic", but rather a matter of applying definitions. Like, why is this website called "english.stackexchange"? It's because someone made up that name. You could say it's circular logic in a sense, "It's called english.stackexchange because that's what it's called". But really, someone makes up a name, then that's what the thing is called. It's not that mysterious a process.

Okay, really I'm oversimplifying when discussing English pronouns. There were plenty of languages around before English was invented that had pronouns, and many (most? all?) of them had masculine, feminine, and neuter. This is an idea that has been around since the beginning of recorded history. The biggest difference between English and other languages is that only apply "he" or "she" to inanimate objects in very rare cases, while other languages attach gender to all sorts of things.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps it would be better if we labelled *it* a 'pertaining-to-things-where-the-concept-of-gender-doesn't-apply' pronoun rather than a 'gender-neutral' pronoun. It certainly doesn't connote indeterminate gender, but rather lack of gender. We don't have a 'gender-indeterminate' pronoun, and it's not constructive to force an unwarranted definition onto 'gender-neutral'.

Humans cannot be considered to fall within a set 'pertaining-to-things-where-the-concept-of-gender-doesn't-apply', but rather (sometimes) within a set 'pertaining-to-things-where-the-concept-of-gender-**does**-apply-but-is-not-relevant-to-the-present-discourse'.

Comment: Or "the gender of the subject may or may not be relevant but is unknown". As many have said in many contexts, it would be nice if there was a pronoun in English to refer to a person of unknown or irrelevant gender. But there isn't, so we continue to struggle with using "they" as a singular pronoun, rewording sentences to avoid the need for a pronoun, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Since *he* and *she* are also available, the use of *it* implies "neither male or female".

Comment: That's my point. "It" is a gender-neutral pronoun, but because "it" is considered dehumanizing, we end up jumping through hoops to come up with an "appropriate" one, and end up with such things as singular they, a slew of "made-up" words, or awkward things like "s/he", "him/her", or "his or hers."

Comment: Note that some transgender folk *prefer* the use of *it*, perhaps similar to homosexuals embracing *queer*.

Comment: @Shauna -- "It" is *not* a gender-neutral pronoun, it's a *neuter* pronoun; the word implies the referent has no gender.

Comment: @Malvolio - Then why are animals and infants sometimes/often referred to as "it"?

Comment: @Zairja - Transgendered people preferring "it" may exist, but they are extraordinarily rare compared to homosexuals who call themselves "queer". Do not call a transgendered person "it" unless they have explicitly asked you to. Ditto "queer" for that matter.

Comment: @Shauna -- parents and the owners of pets get very annoyed when you refer to their little crap-factories as "it".

Comment: It is extremely offensive to refer to a baby or a young child as "it".  Some people also consider it offensive to refer to animals as "it", but only apply this to animals that they happen to be fond of; for example, a person who objects to any pronoun other than "he" for their pet dog may say "it" for the spider they find in the bathtub.

Comment: @DavidWallace The only exception being when the baby's gender is first determined (e.g. parents announcing "it's a girl" or another party asking "was it a boy or girl?").

Comment: @Zairja That's in the general category of the use of "it" as the subject of sentences with a predicate nominative, even when discussing a person. If someone asks, "Who was on the phone?", we answer, "It was Fred", not "He was Fred". Etc.

Answer (score 1):

Because 'it' refers to a thing, not a person. To use it applied to a person is to suggest that they are not a person, but a thing, in the same way that when talking about a person using 'she' implies the person is female.

Of course this has cultural and contextual nuances, some people would not see it as de-humanising, and parents may refer to an unborn child as 'it' having chosen not to know its gender until birth, etc